# Why aren't the images changing with CSS img:nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-animations

I am trying to add animation to 4 images using css. Basically the animation is a transition where each image is displayed for a specific amount of time and then gets changed to the next image. The problem however is, it does not transit to the other image, it only stays in the first image.

Below is my index.html file code

```
<html>
      <head>
         <title>My Test Animation</title>
         <script src = 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> 
   </script>
      <script src = "Scripts/aquaticcenter.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/transitions.css">
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>My Test Animation</h2>

      <div id="cf3">          
       <img  id="cf3" src="/images/test1.jpg" />
       <img  id="cf3" src="/images/test2.jpg" />
       <img  id="cf3" src="/images/test3.jpg" />
      </div>

   </body>


</html>
```

Below is my css code in separate file (transitions.css)

```
#cf3 {
   position:relative;
   height:281px;
   width:450px;
   margin:0 auto;
     }

#cf3 img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }




@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {
     opacity:1;
     }
  17% {
     opacity:1;
     }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
    }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
   }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
   }
}

#cf3 img:nth-of-type(1) {
   animation-delay: 6s;
}
#cf3 img:nth-of-type(2) {
   animation-delay: 4s;
}
#cf3 img:nth-of-type(3) {
   animation-delay: 5s;
}
#cf3 img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

Comment: IDs should be unique. Consider unsing classes.

Comment: you are missing the reference to the animation cf3FadeInOut I believe. Try adding to #cf3 img... animation: cf3FadeInOut 5s infinite; for example. Or where does cf3FadeInOut get referenced?

Comment: @Fluchaa so it means just changing the #cf3 to .cf3 and using class instead of id in the div and image attributes? Sorry i am quite new to css and html

Comment: @Tom I did try that but still it doesn't work.

Comment: you aren't calling the animation at all

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is this correct? 
#cf3 img:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation: cf3FadeInOut 0s;
  }

Comment: `#cf3 img{animation: cf3FadeInOut 2s}` <-- or any duration you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you. It worked. Cheers